# EF4 and Connection String

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I have a 3 tiered project.

1) Project.Data (EDMX file)
2) Project.Model (POCO's)
3) Project.Console (Console app)

I have added the connection string into the `Project.Console`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Project.csdl|res://*/Project.ssdl|res://*/Project.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The `Project.Model` is built using the `EntityObject` T4 Template in VS2010. It generates a `ObjectContext` class, with this constructor:

```
public ProjectEntities() : base("name=ProjectEntities", "ProjectEntities")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

I am just trying to instantiate the `context` object, in the `Project.Console`:

```
namespace Project.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProjectEntities pe = new ProjectEntities();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a `MetadataException was unhandled` error at the constructor. Stating `Unable to load the specified metadata resource.`

I have done a ton of research (Googling), and found that it seems to be a linking issue on those resources. I cannot seem to find a resolution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I read the article that Craig suggested, but I am still uncertain where I have to place the ...dll file reference?  I have a scenario likes yours.  I am assuming in the Project.Model's app.config?  I have my context and pocos separated from the edm file in separate project as in your case, Project.Model.

Comment: In my console project I needed a reference to my data (EDMX) and model project. It also required a reference to System.Data.Entity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a lengthy [guide to debugging this error](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) a while back.

Answer (score 3):

Open your assembly using any resource viewer (e.g., RedGate .NET Reflector) and check that the name of the metadata resource is the same that you have specified in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the *　with your project.data assembly like below

```
<add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://Project.Data/Project.csdl|res://Project.Data/Project.ssdl|res://Project.Data/Project.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```